# Perl HTML parser

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I am having some difficulty in parsing an HTML file.

Here is the part of the HTML file I want to extract the name of the website :

> `<span class="bold1">Name: </span>www.google.com<br />`
>
> `<span class="bold1">Name: </span>www.facebook.com<br />`
>
> `<span class="bold1">Name: </span>www.myspace.com<br />`

Here is the Perl code snippet using `HTML::TreeBuilder` module

```
my @style = $root->look_down('class' => qr/bold1$/);
```

How do we extract the next element here : I would like to extract from the above example :

1. www.google.com
2. www.facebook.com
3. www.myspace.com

> ```
> for (@style) 
> {
>    my $title1 = $_->as_HTML; #text
>    print " title" . $title .  "\n";
> }
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Please only one question per thread, so [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your follow-up. You can get the text from [this question's revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7945049/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`right()`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement#h-right-) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new to website scraping. Thanks a lot.

Comment: on a related note, Updated the question. Thanks